# Removing quotation marks and comma from array of tuples

Tags: python, tuples

I created an array of tuples from a column in a dataframe as such:

```
 subset = df[['sRGB']]
 tuples = [tuple(x) for x in subset.values]
```

Although, in the data frame, the values in the 'sRGB' column are 3 consecutive numbers separated by a comma, the array of tuples comes out as the following with additional quotation marks and a comma:

[image]

I am looking for a way to remove the quotation marks and the unnecessary comma inside each tuple, so that the array of tuples looks like this:

[(45,21, 31), (54, 14, 33)...]

I would greatly appreciate any guidance as I have already spent 2 hours on this!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
tuples = [tuple([int(y) for y in x[0].split(",")]) for x in tuples]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
tuples = [tuple( map(int, val[0].split(','))) for val in tuples]
```